# Can someone help how to convert this array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

What is the best way to convert from this array

```
[{key: "key1", value: "1"},{key: "key2", value: "2"}]
```

to

```
{"key1":"1","key2":"2"}
```

Comment: Use the map function.

Comment: Map won't work because it returns an array of objects, 1 for each input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Array.prototype.reduce`, you can convert it easily as follows.

```js
const input = [{key: "key1", value: "1"},{key: "key2", value: "2"}];
const output = input.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur.key] = cur.value;
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(output);
```

Comment: I think a map would be more appropriate and more efficient.

Comment: map would return an array, reduce would be more efficent.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a simple for loop by iterating your array and storing your keys/values in an object:

```js
const input = [{key: "key1", value: "1"},{key: "key2", value: "2"}];
const out = {};
for (const item of input) {
  out[item.key] = item.value;
}
console.log(out);
```